# recoil cannot handle the error of async selector

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, selector, recoiljs

Recoil allows user to throw error in the async selector, please see [its document](https://recoiljs.org/docs/guides/asynchronous-data-queries#error-handling) to know more.

Both "<ErrorBoundary/>" and "useRecoilValueLoadable()" can be used to process errors of aysnc selector, but both of them can not work normally when I test them.

Here is my code by using "useRecoilValueLoadable()"

```html
import {RecoilRoot, selector, useRecoilValueLoadable} from 'recoil';

const asyncError = selector({
  key: 'asyncError',
  get: async() => { throw new Error("Test Error"); }
});

function Test() {
  const loadable = useRecoilValueLoadable(asyncError);
  return (
    <h1>
      { loadable?.state === 'hasError' ? "Has error" : "No error" }
    </h1>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <Test/>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But, the final result is

[image].

I tried to use <ErrorBoundary/> and got the same unexpected result too! The version of recoil is "0.2.0".

Hi guys, how to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in `ErrorBoundary` component in React. You have to provide one yourself or use a library, for example [react-error-boundary](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-error-boundary).

Then you also have to use `React.Suspense` just like the documentation you referred to states.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <RecoilRoot>
      <ErrorBoundary FallbackComponent={Fallback}>
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div>loading...</div>}>
          <Test />
        </React.Suspense>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </RecoilRoot>
  );
}
```

Also your selector is not async. The error will throw immediately.

Check out [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-waterfall-pyueg?file=/src/App.js:444-705) for a working example.
To learn more about the function of the `ErrorBoundary` component you should read the [official react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).

Comment: Use this inside the get async function to throw asyncly.

Comment: return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // use one of the lines below
      setTimeout(() => resolve("delayed no error"), 3000);      
      setTimeout(() => reject("delayed with error"), 2000);
      throw new Error("Test Error");
    });

Comment: I've communicated with recoil team, it's bug.

The old version of recoil works normally, but newer version are not OK because unit test is missing.

Now, recoil team fixed this problem and added unit test. this problem won't appear again